# How to display approved or rejected leave status?

Tags: php, laravel

**My view:**

[image]

**My controller:**

```
$user_id = auth()->user()->id;
$user = User::find($user_id);
$applications = Application::where('leaveStatus','APPROVED', 'REJECTED')->get(); 
return view('applications.index')->with('applications', $user->applications);
```

How do I display approved or rejected leave status only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't make much sense at the moment:

1. No need to fetch the user from the database when you are already getting them from the `auth()` helper
2. You are not doing anything with the `$applications` variable

What you could do instead is:

```
$applications = auth()->user()
    ->applications()
    ->whereIn('leaveStatus', ['APPROVED', 'REJECTED'])
    ->get();

return view('applications.index', compact('applications'));
```

What we do here is get the authenticated user, load their applications where the `leaveStatus` is `APPROVED` **or** `REJECTED` and then pass it to the view with the help of [compact](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.compact.php):

`compact('applications')` === `['applications' => $applications]`

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#where-clauses):

> The whereIn method verifies that a given column's value is contained
>   within the given array:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
    ->whereIn('id', [1, 2, 3])
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `whereIn` method for that purpose and pass your `$applications` to the view:

```
$applications = Application::whereIn('leaveStatus',['APPROVED', 'REJECTED'])->get(); 
return view('applications.index', compact('applications'));
```

As per the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#where-clauses):

> The whereIn method verifies that a given column's value is contained within the given array

Comment: Please accept the answer if this solved your problem so it can help others as well 

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways :-

1. Using **orWhere()**

Raw Query Structure :-

**select * from TABLENAME
where COLUMNNAME = 'VALUE1' or COLUMNNAME = 'VALUE2';**

In this case VALUE1 = 'APPROVED', VALUE2 = 'REJECTED', COLUMNNAME = 'leaveStatus'

Laravel Query :-

**$applications = Application::where('leaveStatus','APPROVED') 
                            ->orWhere('leaveStatus','REJECTED')->get();**

2. Using **whereIn()**

Raw Query Form :-

**select * from TABLENAME 
where COLUMNNAME in ("VALUE1","VALUE2")**

In this case VALUE1 = 'APPROVED', VALUE2 = 'REJECTED', COLUMNNAME = 'leaveStatus'

Laravel Query :-

**$applications = Application::whereIn('leaveStatus',['APPROVED', 'REJECTED'])->get();**